# Is it possible to specify the IP address for a second database connection on Heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Heroku app and use Heroku Postgres for the main repo. We want to access a second database in a read only manner for some data that is hosted on a third party.

I have seen the answer to multiple databases here but doesn't solve our static ip issue: [How to use multiple databases for one rails 3.1 app in Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677544/how-to-use-multiple-databases-for-one-rails-3-1-app-in-heroku) (ie a SECOND_DATABASE_URL). I should mention that this is read only so much of the active record infrastructure is somewhat irrelevant.

We really just want to make a connection, get back a hash and then inert locally (never doing migrations against this second database), etc...

However, the read-only user they are going to create needs an IP address. Is there any way for me to get a static ip or proxy these MySQL requests easily?

I have seen QuotaGuard static but that looks mainly for http requests. Or could I use it in this scenario.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use multiple databases for one rails 3.1 app in Heroku?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677544/how-to-use-multiple-databases-for-one-rails-3-1-app-in-heroku)

Comment: i've updated - not the same question